# What does the second moment tell us that variance does not?

Tags: variance, moments

What does the second moment tell us that variance does not?

I can wrap my brain around what the first moment tells us, and I can wrap my brain around what the variance tells us, but interpreting the non-central second moment eludes me.

It seems like the second moment is useful for telling us, along with the first moment, what the variance is. Is there additional use beyond $var(X) = \mathbb{E}[X^2] - (\mathbb{E}[X])^2$?

(I'm looking for more of an intuition than a technical answer, something like how variance gives us an idea of how spread out a distribution is.)

Comment: A good point of departure is to notice that the second moment about any value $a$ units away from the mean is the variance plus $a^2.$ From this perspective, you are asking for what $\operatorname{Var}(X) + (a-E[X])^2$ tells you--and that partitioning into two terms strongly suggests an interpretation.

Comment: @whuber That makes it look like a bias-variance decomposition...but bias of what?

Comment: Bias of $E[X]$ relative to $a.$  You are free to select any value of $a$ that you find meaningful.

Comment: @whuber Sure, $a=0$ for the second moment. So the second moment measures nonzero-ness?

Comment: The second moment quantifies the spread around zero, in exactly the same way the variance quantifies the spread around $E[X].$