# Finding the right hypothesis test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, nonparametric

I have two distributions (Generic and Generic Masked) that I want to compare. I want to show that one is distributed closer to 1 than the other, but don't know which hypothesis to test for this. I have tried an anova, but got nonsignificant results, probably because the means are almost equal.

**Which test is best suited for this purpose?**

The ratio $\frac{RMSE_G}{RMSE_{GM}} = 0.61$ with $RMSE = \sqrt{(((1−)^2)}$.
[image]

As suggested, I have tried to compute the bootstrapped distributions like the following. Does that make sense?

The code together with the data can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0yu0yfgn27gh1wg/min_working_example.zip?dl=0)

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import choice
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from math import sqrt
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

volume_df = pd.read_csv('volume.csv')

generic_df = volume_df.loc[volume_df['Processing']=='Generic']
generic_CBV_df = generic_df.loc[generic_df['Contrast']=='CBV']
generic_BOLD_df = generic_df.loc[generic_df['Contrast']=='BOLD']
generic_masked_df = volume_df.loc[volume_df['Processing']=='Generic Masked']
generic_masked_CBV_df = generic_masked_df.loc[generic_masked_df['Contrast']=='CBV']
generic_masked_BOLD_df = generic_masked_df.loc[generic_masked_df['Contrast']=='BOLD']


bootstrapped_RMSEs = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Contrast', 'Processing', 'Uid', 'RMSE'])

N = 10000

for i in range(N):
    generic_CBV_df_temp = choice(generic_CBV_df['Volume Conservation Factor'].to_list(), len(generic_CBV_df['Volume Conservation Factor'].to_list()))
    generic_BOLD_df_temp = choice(generic_BOLD_df['Volume Conservation Factor'].to_list(), len(generic_BOLD_df['Volume Conservation Factor'].to_list()))
    generic_masked_CBV_df_temp = choice(generic_masked_CBV_df['Volume Conservation Factor'].to_list(), len(generic_masked_CBV_df['Volume Conservation Factor'].to_list()))
    generic_masked_BOLD_df_temp = choice(generic_masked_BOLD_df['Volume Conservation Factor'].to_list(), len(generic_masked_BOLD_df['Volume Conservation Factor'].to_list()))
    rmse_generic_masked_CBV = sqrt(mean_squared_error([1] * len(generic_masked_CBV_df_temp), generic_masked_CBV_df_temp))
    rmse_generic_masked_BOLD = sqrt(mean_squared_error([1] * len(generic_masked_BOLD_df_temp), generic_masked_BOLD_df_temp))
    rmse_generic_CBV = sqrt(mean_squared_error([1] * len(generic_CBV_df_temp), generic_CBV_df_temp))
    rmse_generic_BOLD = sqrt(mean_squared_error([1] * len(generic_BOLD_df_temp), generic_BOLD_df_temp))
    bootstrapped_RMSEs =bootstrapped_RMSEs.append(pd.DataFrame([['CBV', 'Generic', 'Uid', rmse_generic_CBV]], columns=['Contrast', 'Processing', 'Uid', 'RMSE']))
    bootstrapped_RMSEs =bootstrapped_RMSEs.append(pd.DataFrame([['BOLD', 'Generic', 'Uid', rmse_generic_BOLD]], columns=['Contrast', 'Processing', 'Uid', 'RMSE']))
    bootstrapped_RMSEs =bootstrapped_RMSEs.append(pd.DataFrame([['CBV', 'Generic Masked', 'Uid', rmse_generic_masked_CBV]], columns=['Contrast', 'Processing', 'Uid', 'RMSE']))
    bootstrapped_RMSEs =bootstrapped_RMSEs.append(pd.DataFrame([['BOLD', 'Generic Masked', 'Uid', rmse_generic_masked_BOLD]], columns=['Contrast', 'Processing', 'Uid', 'RMSE']))

dependent_variable = 'RMSE'
expression = 'Processing*Contrast'
formula = 'Q("{}") ~ {}'.format(dependent_variable, expression)
model = smf.mixedlm(formula, bootstrapped_RMSEs, groups='Uid')
fit = model.fit()
summary = fit.summary()
print(summary)
```

Which gives as a result:

```
       Unnamed: 0   Run  ...  Volume Conservation Factor    1 - Vcf
count   34.000000  34.0  ...                   34.000000  34.000000
mean    50.882353   1.0  ...                    0.946419   0.062395
std     29.877289   0.0  ...                    0.082903   0.076287
min      2.000000   1.0  ...                    0.575684   0.000310
25%     25.750000   1.0  ...                    0.929783   0.016875
50%     51.500000   1.0  ...                    0.956092   0.050646
75%     75.250000   1.0  ...                    0.990213   0.070217
max    100.000000   1.0  ...                    1.063413   0.424316

[8 rows x 7 columns]        Unnamed: 0   Run  ...  Volume Conservation Factor    1 - Vcf
count   34.000000  34.0  ...                   34.000000  34.000000
mean    51.147059   1.0  ...                    0.955220   0.049072
std     29.823859   0.0  ...                    0.032839   0.025756
min      2.000000   1.0  ...                    0.915202   0.001942
25%     26.000000   1.0  ...                    0.926149   0.029295
50%     50.500000   1.0  ...                    0.951704   0.048296
75%     76.250000   1.0  ...                    0.971188   0.073851
max    100.000000   1.0  ...                    1.042673   0.084798


                         Mixed Linear Model Regression Results
========================================================================================
Model:                       MixedLM           Dependent Variable:           Q("RMSE")  
No. Observations:            40000             Method:                       REML       
No. Groups:                  1                 Scale:                        0.0002     
Min. group size:             40000             Likelihood:                   114295.9036
Max. group size:             40000             Converged:                    Yes        
Mean group size:             40000.0                                                    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                             Coef.  Std.Err.    z    P>|z| [0.025 0.975]
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept                                     0.059    0.014   4.324 0.000  0.033  0.086
Processing[T.Generic Masked]                 -0.018    0.000 -90.308 0.000 -0.018 -0.017
Contrast[T.CBV]                               0.035    0.000 177.689 0.000  0.035  0.035
Processing[T.Generic Masked]:Contrast[T.CBV] -0.021    0.000 -77.396 0.000 -0.022 -0.021
Uid Var                                       0.000                                     
========================================================================================
```

Comment: The two distributions seems quite similar in terms of location (the mean), although the blue one seems to have a larger variance. ANOVA assume Gaussian variability, which may not be the case, so perhaps you may want to try bootstrapping the difference between the two distributions (i.e. calculate the bootstrapped distribution of the mean difference, or perhaps the differences in the mode)

Comment: @matteo hmm should I then calculate an ANOVA on the bootstrapped distribution?

Comment: It sounds like you want a test to compare variances, not to compare meas or other measure of location.

Comment: @SalMangiafico yes I was also thinking of comparing the variances, but which test should I use for that? I am looking for one that can also measure the influence of the contrast factor to the volume conservation factor

Comment: @SalMangiafico would it make sense to calculate the bootstrapped distribution of the RMSE?

Comment: For your setup, maybe it makes the most sense to compare generic vs. masked within each contrast, with something like Levene's or Bartlett's.  Or, you could treat your treatments as four groups, and use something like Levene's test.  A somewhat more subtle approach is to create a representative linear model model and use Breusch Pagan test.  But I think on the end you'll want to compare groups pairwise, either across all four groups or within contast.

Comment: Using rmse might make sense.  Is this any better than just calculating the ratio of the variances or standard deviations?

Comment: Have a look at my conversation with whuber: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/448209/what-does-the-second-moment-tell-us-that-variance-does-not. You want to examine the spread around $a=1$. I would say to adapt the usual variance formula to $a=1$ instead of $a=\bar{x}$ and try either a permutation test or bootstrap of the difference between your two groups.

Comment: @Jimmy2027 you can use the bootstrap to estimate the distribution of the statistic of interest, which for example could be the difference between Generic and Generic-masked (e.g. the difference of their mean values) or as Dave suggest the spread around 1. You don't need further tests like ANOVA, because you can use this distribution to calculate, for example, a 95% confidence interval on the difference and see whether it includes zero.

Comment: @matteo I have tried to compute the bootstrapped RMSE distributions, but I still don't get a significant effect of the workflow factor. I've put the results as an edit to the post