# Is there any significance to derivatives of the moment generating function about non-zero values?

Tags: random-variable, expected-value, moments, moment-generating-function

The $n^{th}$ derivative about zero of the moment generating function gives the expected value of the $n^{th}$ power of the random variable.

$E[X^n] = M^n(0)$

What about the derivatives about something other than zero? Do they have a significance? Are they ever used?

Comment: Variance is the second moment about the expected value, which might not be zero. You may be interested in whuber’s comments to a question I posted: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/448209/what-does-the-second-moment-tell-us-that-variance-does-not.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I'm sorry, I had miswrote the question. What I meant was the derivatives of the MGF about non zero values. Nonetheless, the comments in that question are also very insightful/useful for me.